# Reducing overhead when accessing objects used by thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, freepascal, lazarus

A thread is looping through a list of 1000 objects every second.
The objects hold simple configuration data. When some conditons are met, a worker thread is given the configuration data and does some work based on that.

Now I want to bring up a settings dialog with the configuration data so I can change the data inside such an object. But then I have to access objects in the list while the thread is also continously accessing them. I know how to use a critical section, but if the thread enters a critical section each time it checks on an object, then the critical section will be entered and left 1000 times per second. Maybe there is a smarter way?

How to make threadsafe with the least overhead when:

a) loading the config data into the settings dialog form (which uses a TListView in virtual mode and needs to access the list of objects on demand)

b) and saving the form input back to the object?

EDIT: More detail was requested.

The objects are in a TList and basically look like this:

```
TConfigData = class
  ID:Integer;
  Name: String;
  SwitchTime: TDateTime;
end;
```

The data of the ConfigData object needs to be loaded into the Settings Dialog form so it can be edited, and then, if the user clicks OK, the ConfigData object should be updated and the thread will happily use this new data next time the obkect is accessed. However, updating must not happen at the same time as the thread is reading the ConfigData object.

EDIT 2: Additional details:

The threads are reading ID, Name and SwitchTime but only SwitchTime is changed by threads. (When work is done, new time is calculated and thats what triggers next work event).

The settings dialog can change both Name and SwitchTime, but not ID.

Comment: You could set a boolean indicating that critical section needs to be checked. Reading and writing the boolean variable is atomic.

Comment: @Gray That doesn't help. Thread A reads false and proceeds. Before it can read, thread B has set the flag true and started modifying. If you could really use a boolean like this, why would locks exist?

Comment: @Rimfire Sounds like you need a better design. We could only guess what it should be since you didn't provide much detail. Very hard to advise on how to work with data whose makeup we know nothing at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have now added more details. The question was tagged Delphi, Lazarus and FreePascal. Why did you remove Delphi and Lazarus?

Comment: Because you are using FreePascal rather than Delphi and because the IDE isn't relevant to what amounts to a coding design issue.

Comment: I still can't see enough info to offer advice. I'd want to know what the various threads were doing with the data. Reading/writing? Which fields? Where does the data come from/go to? Etc. I'd question the use of classes here, it feels more like a value. Perhaps a compare and swap lock free type of approach might be better. But I don't think there's anywhere near enough info.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan FreePascal doesn't have the TListView mentioned in my question. TListView is a component of Delphi and Lazarus.

Comment: Either you are using Delphi, or you are using FreePascal. Which is it? Anyway, I think you need to understand your problem better so that you can ask a clear question here.

Comment: I am a delphi user since 1997 and use both Delphi and Lazarus. TListView doesn't exist in FreePascal, so tagging it with FreePascal is only partly correct. I still think the audience for this question is best reflected in the original tagging: Delphi, Lazarus, FreePascal.

Comment: Best way is to make a copy of the config for editing purposes and after edit, notify the thread that data has been changed and use the copy as new config...

Comment: I agree with whosrdaddy. You should store the new changed data as separate copy and then simply notify your worker thread that one of the objects needs to be updated. The actual update of the objects data can then actually be preformed by worker thread itself so you don't need to resolve using classic synchronization methods like Critical section.

Comment: Use a threadsafe queue to inform the worker thread that you request access to certain object. The worker thread posts the parameters back to the main thread for editing. When editing is done, send the data back to the worker thread through the threadsafe queue. The worker thread can then safely update the object.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True, wasn't thinking it through. Take a look at my proposed solution.

Comment: @Gray I don't understand the problem yet.

Comment: Several interesting suggestions here. Need a bit of time to digest it before I come back with input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of thought, you can get away without using critical sections at all just by using InterlockedExchangePointer:

You need to add a routine to update the config for an item:

```
procedure TMyThread.UpdateConfig(const aIndex: Integer; const aID:Integer;
    const aName: String; const aSwitchTime: TDateTime);
var
  newConfigToEdit: TConfigData;
  oldValue: TConfigData;
begin
  newConfigToEdit := TConfigData.Create;
  newConfigToEdit.ID := aID;
  newConfigToEdit.Name := aName;
  newConfigToEdit.SwitchTime := aSwitchTime;
  repeat
    oldvalue := InterlockedExchangePointer(FConfigDataList.List[aIndex], newConfigToEdit);
  until (oldvalue <> nil) and (oldValue <> newConfigToEdit);
  oldvalue.Free; // Free the replaced one
end;
```

That routine would replace the config for the item with Index of `aIndex`. To get the config in your thread you will need to be a bit clever. We get a copy of it and replace the value in the list with nil while we are working on it. This prevents the other thread from replacing it. Once we have finished we put back the replaced value.

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  configToUse: TConfigData;
begin
  repeat
    // Get the config and replace it with nil so it won't be changed
    configToUse := InterlockedExchangePointer(FConfigDataList.List[idx], nil);
    // Do stuff with the config

    // Put the config back
    FConfigDataList.List[idx] := configToUse;
    // You could also use the line below instead of the assignment
    // InterlockedExchangePointer(FConfigDataList.List[idx], configToUse);
  until Terminated;
end;
```

If you want to kick off a worker thread with the config then you should make a clone of it and then pass in the clone to the worker because it can be changed.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow.

Comment: It seems like this could be greatly simplified by dispensing with the flag and the event. Just acquire the critical section each time through the loop. The overhead of entering a critical section in the absence of contention is minimal. When done a thousand times per second, it might add up, but at only once per second, it should hardly be noticeable at all.

Comment: @RobKennedy The OP did say it was a thousand times per second :) - That said, this solution is about limiting the critical sections. The OP will need to determine if it's worthwhile going through the effort.

Comment: @RobKennedy No need for critical sections. I have replaced the code with a simpler cleaner lock free version  :)

Answer (score -2):

Main thread (pseudo)code (ObjList is the global variable):

```
if ConfigUpdated(i) then
  ObjList[i].ConfigVersion := ObjList[i].ConfigVersion + 1;
```

Other thread(s) (pseudo)code (ObjConfVer is the local for thread)

```
for i := 0 to ObjCount - 1 do
  if ObjConfVer[i] < ObjList[i].ConfigVersion then
  begin
    // Here you have to take care that main thread will can not change config  while you handling it
    // Do something about new config
    ObjConfVer[i] := ObjList[i].ConfigVersion;
    // Exit from critical section
  end;
```

If you have `n` threads which works with the same `ObjList` it is allow to each thread doing something about changed config independently.

BTW if you are using FPC/Lazarus this link may be usefull: [Parallel procedures](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Parallel_procedures)

Comment: I cannot see any synchronization here. What's to stop the `if ObjConfVer[i] < ObjList[i].ConfigVersion then` returning true, but then the other thread changing `ObjList[i].ConfigVersion` an instant later, before the first thread does what it needs to do?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So what? Data was changed anywhere and it must be handled. Main point is that to prevent to handle partially data changes. So there is : 1) change data 2) inc the flag 3) see that flag was increased and stop (notify) the main thread 4) Handle new data 5) release main thread

Comment: It seems to me that without synchronisation you have a race

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I mention that main thread can RW and other threads can only R of global data, so, no any race if I correctly understand what is the `race` at all.

Comment: It's a race when one thread reads and another thread writes without synchronisation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So we are need something like transaction. What i trying to provide: 1) change data 2) inc the flag value that data was changed (1-2-3 times while secondary thread(s) was busy) 3) wait while changes will handled. 4) We are ready for the next activity.

Comment: Whatever you are proposing, when share data without synchronization, you have a race.

Comment: Abelisto: while you are changing data, and have changed the first, but not the second one, the thread is already using it in this inconsistent state. Probably the solution is something with a private set for the thread, and setting a boolean triggers the thread to block on proper synchronization primitives to receive a new thread.  Strictly speaking you need to use something locked for that (in case of multi CPU systems) to synchronize the memory systems.